# What's the most "death-resistant" component on Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-lifecycle

I'm looking for the most suitable class to be a dispatcher for AsyncTasks invoked from my Activities.

I think it could be one of these:

1. subclass of **Application**;
2. subclass of **Service**;
3. my own **static** stuff.

As for me - it's simlier to implement the 3rd choice. But the question is will it be more "death-resistant" than Service or Application? Also it's very interesting what will live longer - Application or Service? My guess is the Application lives as long as the app (task in terms of Android) process lives.

So basically I need to range those options by their "death-resistant" quality, because I'd like to rely on the most "static" thing.

**UPDATE:**

Originally the question was asked in **2010**, when (1) Android was new platform for developers and (2) Google documentation was too vague (in some cases it was even misleading) about app components life-cycles and the entire app process life-cycle.

Comment: I immediately delete applications from my phone that insist on being "death proof".

Comment: You may want to explain what you are trying to achieve more clearly. Right now it sounds like you are trying to make it impossible to close your app which is something you're going to be hard-pressed to get advice for.

Comment: It is not recommended and harms user experience and battery life

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments! I probably should explain what I am trying to achieve more clearly. So, Activity can start AsyncTask. The AsyncTask, for instance, posts http request to register a new user. Since Activity is an OS-killable component (may be killed if a Phone app jumps up) it may happen that AsyncTask is unable to pass the request result back to Activity. So on restore the Activity will have to rerun the AsyncTask, but I don't want to resend the same credentials again and alerting user with "such username already in use".

Comment: That's why I need a mechanism to store AsyncTask results, so on when Activity restores itself it could ask for the pending result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

The main reason behind this - `Service` has it's own documented **life-cycle**, while Application doesn't. `Application` instance, like any of your static variables, can be killed by system almost at any time, you will not receive any callback and can't stop this process. So, any unsaved data (all static variables) will be lost.

On the other hand, `Service` can't be killed by system silently, at least `onDestroy()` method should be called first. Having such callback, you can save your state to some persistent memory (like SharedPreferences, file, database, etc) and restore that state next time your Application or Service starts.

Comment: thanks for the response! ;) well, I asked this question more than 2 years ago and by now I've already come to the same solution of using `Service` and the rest of the Android specific stuff that eventually ends in an Android scpecific architecture (which is not smth that immediately comes to the mind when you've just switched from BlackBerry development :) ). Anyway thanks. +1